# Unallocated space instead of LUKS partition with gparted

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, luks, fdisk, testdisk

I have unplugged a USB with valuable data with a mounted LUKS partition which destroyed the partition table.

Running `testdisk` does not recognized the partition: it claim it as unallocated space instead of a LUKS partition. From `parted`:

```
Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  3222MB  3221MB  primary               boot
 2      3222MB  3224MB  2097kB  primary
```

There should be a third LUKS type partition

```
Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  3222MB  3221MB  primary               boot
 2      3222MB  3224MB  2097kB  primary
 3      3224MB  16.0GB  12.8GB  primary
```

I tried adding a new partition with `testdisk` for this apparent unallocated space but didn't found the `crypt_LUKS` type in the list:

```
>List of partition type 
[...]                                                  
 1e hid. FAT16 LBA       87 HPFS FT mirror-V/S set f0 Linux/PA-RISC boot
 20 Willowsoft OFS1      8e Linux LVM            f1 Storage Dimensions
[...]
```

Hence my first question:

**1. Is `Linux LVM` the right type for a LUKS encrypted partition? Which method should be used to force to recognize the unallocated space as a LUKS partition**

Choosing `Linux LVM` does not allow to run `cryptsetup luksOpen` (I get `Device /dev/sdb1 is not a valid LUKS device.`)

**2. Which other method would you use in order to recover my LUKS partition recognized as unallocated space ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux doesn't care about partition types. Just give it any type which is not a Windows type; Linux LVM works well, or 0xDA (Non-FS Data). To check whether a device, for example, `/dev/sdc3` is a LUKS container:

```
sudo cryptsetup isLuks /dev/sdc3 && echo LUKS container || echo Not a LUKS container
```

The best way is to recreate the partition as it was and, if necessary, restore the LUKS header from backup. Backup the first 2 MiB of the partition first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It says "Not a LUKS container". However I think my partition can be the 2nd and 3rd merged since the 2nd is detected as having a LUKS header.

Comment: Then instead of making a 3rd partition just set the end of the second at the end of the disk.

Comment: I deleted and recreated a partition with `fdisk`. Data recovered.